# Spring boot startup logs to file

Tags: spring-boot, logging

Is it anyway to send startup logs to file, right now all logs up to the statement "Started Application in...." goes to stdout, I want all logging to file.

My logback config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="logs/app${PID}.log"/>

    <appender name="AI-APPENDER"
              class="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.logback.ApplicationInsightsAppender">
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>${LOG_FILE_MAX_SIZE:-10MB}</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="AI-APPENDER"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What version of spring-boot are you using? If you want to include the banner in the log you can set spring.main.banner-mode=log in the application.properties.

Comment: banner is not the problem, want to have startup logs to file

Comment: It works for me with springboot v 2.1.0 on linux. Can you mention what version you use?

Comment: yea it seems it is some application insight jar:s that break it, I investigate it right now.

Comment: the problem was commons-configuration took in commons-logging when I exclude that I start to get logging to file also exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your logging framework. Assuming you're just using the default from spring-boot then that's LogBack. So have a look at [their docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) or have a search, there are many useful resources ([like this one](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/default-logging.html))

If you add a logback.xml file with the following content to your resources folder you should get logging to both console and file (called application.log) in the same format as you now see for just console.

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>application.log</file>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

You probably want to use a [RollingFileAppender](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) as this will allow you to create new files when the log file gets big.

Comment: I updated case with my logback config, the problem is that startup logs is not ende up in my app log file, when the application is up and running it works.